# Problems reading unicode input in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to read a Unicode string from input and i'm using wide chars for this. When I'm inputting an ASCII string it works just fine, but when I'm inputting cyrillics the input seems to be empty.

```cpp
#include <cstdio> 
#include <string> 
#include <cwchar> 

int main() { 
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); 
        wchar_t c[64]; 
        wscanf(L"%ls", c); 
        wprintf(L"%d", wcslen(c)); 
        return 0; 
}
```

```
< hello
> 5
< алло
> 0
```

Comment: 1) The standard library is rather ill-equipped to do "real" Unicode handling. You can get by when all you're doing is passing data through, but for *handling* Unicode (stuff like comparing, sorting, normalization, tokenization etc.), you're better off using the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/). There's better Unicode support (hopefully) coming up in a future version of the standard, but as of now, be aware that `std::` is very limited. -- 2) Don't read potentially malformed (user) input with `*scanf()`, especially not without checking the return value. That's UB waiting to happen.

Comment: the problem is that i'm doing a lab project and i cannot use any external libraries. i have to use what i have with just crude c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not check *any* return values. In this case, I would be looking askance at the return from `setlocale`, because I am pretty sure that call failed and returned `NULL`.

Which locales you can set is depending on which locales are actually *installed* on your machine.

On Linux, you can get a list of *possible* locales from `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`:

```
$ grep -i ru /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED 
ce_RU UTF-8
cv_RU UTF-8
mhr_RU UTF-8
os_RU UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8
ru_RU.KOI8-R KOI8-R
ru_RU ISO-8859-5
ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251
ru_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8
ru_UA KOI8-U
tt_RU UTF-8
```

You will note that it is not "rus", but "ru_RU.UTF-8". But is that locale actually *installed* on your machine? You can get a list of *installed* locales via `locale -a`, and you can *install* a new locale by `locale-gen`, which requires superuser rights.

So,

- check that the desired locale is actually installed on your system,
- use the correct identifier for the locale,
- check that `setlocale` actually succeeded.

All that being said, note that you're using C functionality here. You are probably better off using C++ `locale` / `<iostream>` instead of `<clocale>` / type-unsafe `<cstdio>`.